# Explain where trailing spaces are and aren't ignored in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, string, t-sql, patindex, trailing-whitespace

I believed trailing spaces are ignored in SQL everywhere until I encountered a scenario with PATINDEX where they aren’t ignored.

Case 1: `SELECT PATINDEX('qwerty', 'qwerty')` returns 1.
Case 2: `SELECT PATINDEX('qwerty', 'qwerty ')` returns 1. A trailing space inserted at the end of the second string is ignored.
Case 3: `SELECT PATINDEX('qwerty ', 'qwerty')` returns 0.

Why it didn’t ignore the trailing space inserted at the end of the first string just like Case 2?

Answer (score 1):

> I believed trailing spaces are ignored in SQL everywhere

No, they are not. They are ignored for comparison purposes only, that's it. So `'mystring '` and `'mystring'` would be treated the same in the clause `WHERE 'mystring' = 'mystring '`.

They are not, however in things like using `PATINDEX`.

Note that it is documented in the `LEN` function that trailing spaces are also ignored. `DATALENGTH` on the other hand, includes them.

Comment: Exactly my question. Trailing spaces aren't ignored in PATINDEX but ignored at other places like WHERE, LEN, etc. Trailing spaces are inserted to complete the length while storing a value in a table so not ignored in DATALENGTH. Are there any other places where they are not ignored? How would I identify, is there a rule or something?